# I'm getting the suggested edits notification even though I'm a <10k rep user

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

Every now an then, the suggested edits notification pops up, but I'm not allowed to visit https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits (getting the *Page not found* page), so I guess it's a mod tool for 10k+ users.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, this should be fixed now.